# How to calculate $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{x^2 - y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How do I show that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{x^2 - y^2} = 0$? I tried using polar coordinates, and arrived at $\lim_{r \to 0^+}r \tan{(2\theta)} \sin \theta$. But then, I couldn't find a nice way to prove that this is zero, because the function multplying $r$ isn't bounded. Does anyone have a nice, simple solution?

Comment: Well, if you can't prove it's zero, perhaps it's because the limit might not exist...

Comment: [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7B(x%2C%20y)%20%5Cto%20(0%2C0)%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bxy%5E2%7D%7Bx%5E2%20-%20y%5E2%7D%24&p=1) gives many hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by $x=t+t^2$ and $y=t$ with $t\to 0^+$

$$\frac{xy^2}{x^2 - y^2}=\frac{t^3+t^4}{2t^3+t^4 }=\frac{1+t}{2+t } \to \frac12$$

therefore, since you also find paths with limit equal to zero, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: It's $y^2$ not $y$, so the numerator should be $t^{3}+t^{4}$. So it reduces to $$\frac{1+t}{2+t}$$.

Comment: For an infinite limit use $f(t,t-t^3)$, yet I prefer $f(t,t\sqrt{1-t})=1-t\to 1$ which is rather nice.

Comment: @Äres Thanks I fix it!

Comment: @zwim Yes that's also a nice way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once you realize that the denominator blows up when you approach the origin moving around the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ (because $y^2-x^2 =(x-y)(x+y)$), you have a key to find "nice curves" that will prove the non-existence of the limit.

Take for example $\color{red}{y = x} + x^2$ and $\color{blue}{y = -x} + x^2$ and you will see the magic. You can also toy around with $y= x + x^3$ or $y= x + \sqrt{x}$ to find different behaviors of the function near the origin.